# javascript closure in for loop not working

Tags: javascript, cordova, callback, closures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

I'm having a problem with a closure in a phonegap application. I have a JSON object which contains instructions on how to create a form. This is roughly the code:

```
for (var i in this.form.elements) {
    var element = this.form.elements[i];
    switch (element.type) {
        // other cases
        case 5:
            var addThumb, photoInput;
            addThumb = function (domId) {
                return function (imgData) {
                    console.log('id: ' + domId);
                    $(domId).attr({src: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imgData});
                }
            }('#thumb-'+element.id);
            photoInput = $('<input>')
                .attr({type: 'button', value: element.name, name: element.type, id: element.id, 'class': 'photobutton'})
                .click(function (filename, cb) {
                    return function() {
                        console.log('taking photo and saving to ' + filename)
                        takePhoto(filename,addThumb)
                    }
                }('photo-'+element.id, addThumb)
            );
            photoThumb = $('<img>').attr({id: 'thumb-'+element.id, 'class': 'thumbnail', src: 'img/target.png'});
            $('#content').append(photoInput, photoThumb);
            break;
    }
}
```

Clicking the photobutton opens up a camera to take a picture, which is saved to disk. Once saved, addThumb is called with the base64 photo data to replace the thumbnail image. The output for each for my test form is:

```
taking photo and saving to file photo-686
id: '#thumb-690
```

The closure for taking the photo works, but when addThumb is called as a callback, `domId` shows the last element.id that went through the for loop. Given two thumbnails, the second one is always replaced regardless of the button pressed. It happens on both iPhone and Android so there must be a problem with the way I've written it. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Is `this.form` a true `form` element on the page?

Comment: this.form is just an object, no html elements. It has the mapping for what html elements to make and what their ids and values should be, like values for combo boxes.

Comment: I guess `form.elements` is array-like, so you should not use a for-in-loop here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
takePhoto(filename, addThumb)
```

You need to pass the `cb` variable from inside the closure here, not the `addThumb` which is not "protected". Seems like you forgot to change the variable name when "protecting" it.

Comment: +1 My explication is right, but yours captures OP's intent. It's much better and useful than mine.

Comment: You are correct! Thanks for spotting it, you and @dystroy.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `addThumb` variable itself isn't protected by a closure. It encloses the value of `element.i`d at the time it is created but it's replaced in the next occurrence of the loop. So you're always calling the last created `addThumb` function.

Instead of trying to protect each variable separately, you could build one closure to enclose `element` :

```
for (var i in this.form.elements) {
    var element = this.form.elements[i];
    (function(element){
       switch (element.type) {
       ...
    })(element);
}
```